# Allow auto hide of the "How it works" banner

Tags: feature-request, design

Whenever I visit a site I have not yet an account for, I get the same "How it works" banner. Sometimes the big version, sometimes the smaller version, I don't know how that's decided. If I get the big version, I have to make **two** clicks to hide it completely because the first click turns it into the small version.

Here is an example from "Ask Patents":

Big version on first visit:
[image]

Small version on first click:
[image]

Especially the bigger version takes up a lot of space and most of the content shows things I already know. The smaller version has some value because it summarizes what this site is about (although I think in most cases the title is enough).

What I'd like would be a setting for all *.stackexchange.com sites that hides these banners at all or—at the very least—immediately causes display of the small version.

Comment: Could at least the downvoter explain what's wrong? I think this should be opt-in, so there should be no problem for genuine new users who might find this introduction useful.